# Elements of website are too small on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile-website, bootstrap-5

I am making a website for my discord bot - Idle Baker. For this website, I decided to use the latest [**Bootstrap 5**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/) to design since it is easier than a whole lot of CSS.

I have coded the home-page of the website but before I could move any further I realized a problem, when I loaded the website in mobile form in browser-devtools, the scaling for my elements, navbar were very tiny. It looks perfectly fine on PC and bigger screen devices. I will also be providing the code below.

Also here are 3 images:

**Normal PC Resolution**
[image: Normal PC Resolution]

**Abnormal Mobile Resolution**
[image: Abnormal Mobile Resolution]

**Normal Mobile Resolution on external website**
[image: Normal Mobile Resolution on external website]

```js
AOS.init();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap');
.parallax {
  background-image: url("./assets/bg_pic.png");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
}

.floating {
  animation-name: floating;
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.box-glow {
  animation: glowing 3000ms infinite;
}

.fa_color {
  color: #ffffff
}

.btn-primary-spacing {
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}

.multicolortext {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(238, 255, 0), rgb(255, 0, 64));
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}

@keyframes floating {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0, 15px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(0, -0px);
  }
}

@keyframes glowing {
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 -10px #c4a300;
  }
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #c4a300;
  }
  60% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #c4a300;
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 -10px #c4a300;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/aos@2.3.1/dist/aos.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.4/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body style="font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif; color:#FFFFFF" class="parallax">
  <div data-aos="zoom-out" data-aos-duration="1750">
    <div class="container-xxl container-fluid rounded" id="navbar-main">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand " href="http://127.0.0.1:5500/index.html">
          <img src="./assets/logo.png" alt="Idle Baker " width="75 " height="75 " class="d-inline-block align-top ">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#main-nav" aria-controls="main-nav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end align-center" id="main-nav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto text-center">
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link btn-lg btn-outline-warning p-3 mx-2 rounded-pill" href="index.html">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link btn-lg btn-outline-warning p-3 mx-2 rounded-pill" href="about.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link btn-lg btn-outline-warning p-3 mx-2 rounded-pill" href="starter.html">Starter Guide</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link btn-lg btn-outline-warning p-3 mx-2 rounded-pill" href="commands.html">Commands</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link btn-lg btn-outline-warning p-3 mx-2 rounded-pill" href="donate.html">Donate</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link btn-lg btn-outline-warning p-3 mx-2 rounded-pill" href="index.html#vote-for-us">Vote</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link btn-lg btn-outline-warning p-3 mx-2 rounded-pill" href="https://discord.gg/395rp63rCY">Join Official Server</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a class="nav-link btn-lg btn-outline-warning p-3 mx-2 rounded-pill" href="https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=821958079670124614&permissions=8&scope=bot">Invite</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="text-center mx-5">
      <br>
      <br>

      <section id="main-buttons" class="row">
        <div class="rounded-pill p-3 shadow border border-dark border-2 floating container-fluid" style="background-color:#2B2E33 ">
          <div class="buttons">
            <h1 class="display-5 text-center mt-5 fw-bolder multicolortext">Idle Baker</h1>
            <h3 class="display-10 text-center mt-3 mb-4 fw-bold ">The bot to make your server perfect </h3>
            <a href="https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=821958079670124614&permissions=8&scope=bot " class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-warning p-3 box-glow btn-block btn-primary-spacing ">Add to Server</button></a>
            <a href="https://discord.gg/395rp63rCY " class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-warning p-3 btn-block btn-primary-spacing box-glow">Join Support Server</button></a>
            <a href="https://top.gg/bot/821958079670124614/vote " class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-warning p-3 btn-block btn-primary-spacing box-glow">Vote for Rewards</button></a>
          </div>
          <br>
          <br>
        </div>
      </section>

    </div>

    <div>

      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="text-center mx-4 ">
        <a href="#bake-command">
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down center animate__animated animate__rubberBand animate__infinite animate__slow fa-5x fa_color animate__delay-3s "></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center mx-5 my-1">
      <br>

      <section class="floating" id="bake-command">
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center rounded-pill p-5 shadow border border-dark border-2 " style="background-color:#2B2E33 ">
          <div class="col mx-3 p-5 ">
            <h1 class="multicolortext">Bake Stuff</h2>
              <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Hic similique perferendis aliquam ad, praesentium asperiores sapiente delectus ipsum, ut doloribus fuga consequuntur repudiandae repellendus nam dolores assumenda atque quidem
              maiores.
              <br>
          </div>
          <div class="col mx-3">
            <img src="./assets/bake_command.png " class="img-fluid ">
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
      </section>

    </div>

    <div class="text-center mx-5 my-1">
      <section class="floating" id="sell-command">
        <div class=" row justify-content-center align-items-center rounded-pill p-5 shadow border border-dark border-2 " style="background-color:#2B2E33 ">
          <div class="col mx-3 ">
            <img src="./assets/sell_command.png " class="img-fluid">
          </div>
          <div class="col mx-3 p-5 ">
            <h1 class="multicolortext">Sell it</h2>
              <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam ex a eaque harum voluptas, pariatur ipsa inventore alias accusantium quisquam numquam eveniet accusamus eos in. Temporibus quasi vitae repellendus tempora?
              <br>
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
      </section>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center mx-5 my-1">
      <section class="floating" id="shop-command">
        <br>
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center rounded-pill p-5 shadow border border-dark border-2" style="background-color:#2B2E33 ">
          <div class="col mx-3 p-5 ">
            <h1 class="multicolortext">Buy Upgrades</h2>
              <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Hic similique perferendis aliquam ad, praesentium asperiores sapiente delectus ipsum, ut doloribus fuga consequuntur repudiandae repellendus nam dolores assumenda atque quidem
              maiores.
              <br>
          </div>
          <div class="col mx-3 ">
            <img src="./assets/shop_command.png " class="img-fluid">
          </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
      </section>
    </div>

    <div class="text-center mx-5 my-1">
      <section class="floating" id="vote-for-us">
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center rounded-pill p-5 shadow border border-dark border-2 " style="background-color:#2B2E33 ">
          <h1 class="multicolortext">Vote and Earn Rewards</h2>
            <br>
            <br>
            <h4 class="strong">Earn $10,000 in-game currency and 2 bakers (30 minutes each)</h4>
            <div class="col mx-3">
              <a href="https://top.gg/bot/821958079670124614">
                <img src="https://top.gg/api/widget/821958079670124614.svg" alt="Idle Baker" width="350px" height="350px">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col mx-3">
              <a href="https://discordbotlist.com/bots/821958079670124614">
                <img src="https://discordbotlist.com/api/v1/bots/821958079670124614/widget" alt="Idle Baker" width="382px" height="214px" class="shadow">
              </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
      </section>
    </div>

    <section id="footer"></section>

  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
```

Comment: "I decided to use the latest Bootstrap 5 to design since it is easier than a whole lot of CSS." - **debatable** - I'm going to strongly disagree with you there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is with the meta tag. Your viewport meta tag is not being considered as what it is intended to by the browser because of a space in "" like `"viewport "`

```
<meta name="viewport " content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0 ">
```

That is causing the responsiveness to break. Change it to `"viewport"` and check for the spaces in other tags too.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: sure, ill try that

Comment: Thanks a lot! Was just a matter of a space key. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score -2):

Have you opened the page on an actual mobile device? Try that and then let us know.

But right off the bat you are going to need media queries to properly size your elements for different viewports.

Here is the MDN documentation

[Using media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Yes, I tried it on a mobile device just to be sure. I still get the same result...

Comment: Gvie the media queries a try and see what results you can obtain. Im more than certain that's what you'll need.